# How can I change the values of a column in pandas ? the values are stored as a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do multiple operations on an entire column of a dataframe.

Here is a sample data:

```
df['raw_col'] = '2019/03/20 11:31:51 AM, 2019/03/20 11:19:32 AM'
```

1. I want to split this column into a list

`df['raw_col'] = ['2019/03/20 11:31:51 AM', '2019/03/20 11:19:32 AM']`

2. I want to access each element of this list and change the string value to DateTime and also add time delta (e.g, change each timestamp to UTC)
3. Finally, I want to store the result in a new column and as a list.

`df['new_col'] = ['2019/03/20 16:31:51 PM', '2019/03/20 16:19:32 PM'] (These time stamps are in UTC)`

I figured out the first part

`df['raw_col'] = df['raw_col'].str.split(',').tolist()`

and I am hoping to get some help on 2nd and 3rd parts

Comment: For step 2, use `to_datetime`.